# Probability property that the longest side of primitive Pythagorean triples is prime

Tags: probability, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

If we consider the set of the first $n$ primitive Pythagorean triples, then the probability that the triple's longest side is prime is approximately $\dfrac{1}{\log_{11.475}n}$ based on Mathematica’s $\tt{FindFit}$ and some code of mine.

Is this result known? If so, is the base of this logarithm in closed form known?

([More information about how this approximation was generated is here.](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0vfDp0jjCw9SWh3Zm9WcnI3Wm8/edit?usp=sharing))

Comment: I would recommend writing your result the form $\frac C{\ln n}$ and finding $C$, rather than trying to find the base of the logarithm; this is more likely to produce a 'nice' number, since the baseline property of a number being prime is essentially $\frac 1{\ln n}$.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "the first $n$"?  First in what order?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer, but here's some relevant information:

All pythagorean triples can be represented as, given $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{N}$, $a=\alpha^2-\beta^2$, $b=2\alpha\beta$, and $c=\alpha^2+\beta^2$. I assume you are talking about irreducible triples, so we can set $GCD(\alpha,\beta)=1$.  So, your question is really the probability of a sum of two coprime squares being prime.

Notes on sums of squares and number theory:

Sums of squares are actually closed under multiplication: $$(i^2+j^2)(k^2+l^2)=(ik-jl)^2+(il+jk)^2$$ and you can check that the two resultant squares will also be coprime.  Moreover, a sum of two squares can never be a prime that is $3\pmod{4}$ (or any number $3\pmod{4}$ for that matter), while every prime $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ can be expressed as a sum of $2$ squares.  This means that the problem further reduces to finding the distribution of primes in numbers not divisible by odd exponents of numbers that are equivalent to $3\pmod{4}$ (sums of squares can be divisible by the square of primes that are $3\pmod{4}$).